# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

recently i've been working on my custom discord bot in discord.js.

Today i modified my command handler and got into this error while trying to use my .play command that plays music through my bot:

```
(node:481) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/MaikuBot/commands/play.js:14:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MaikuBot/index.js:29:34)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14) at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10) at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/MaikuBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16) (node:481) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

So here is my .play command code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
var volume = 0.5;

const queue = new Map();
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['p', 'skip', 'clear', 'volUp', 'volDown'],
    cooldown: 0,
    description: "Play music trought bot",
    async execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord) {
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (voice_channel != null) {
            if (!voice_channel) {
                return message.reply("Devi essere in un canale vocale.");
            }
            const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        //If the user has used the play command
        if (cmd === 'play' || cmd === 'p'){
            if (!args.length) return message.reply('Per favore completa il comando!');
            let song = {};

            //If the first argument is a link. Set the song object to have two keys. Title and URl.
            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                //If there was no link, we use keywords to search for a video. Set the song object to have two keys. Title and URl.
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Non ho trovato il video...');
                }
            }

            //If the server queue does not exist (which doesn't for the first video queued) then create a constructor to be added to our global queue.
            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }
                
                //Add our key and value pair into the global queue. We then use this to get our server queue.
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
    
                //Establish a connection and play the song with the vide_player function.
                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send("C'è stato un errore durante la connessione al canale...");
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(` Ho aggiunto "**${song.title}**" alla coda`)
                .setColor('#36393F')
                .setAuthor('maiku', 'https://i.ibb.co/MCkG7wV/M-ROSSA-500.png', 'https://discord.gg/QNhpmbG3Sm')
                .setDescription(`[**Brano aggiunto alla coda corretamente**]`);
                await server_queue.text_channel.send(Embed);
                console.log(`[ll] Ho aggiunto "${song.title}" alla coda`);
            }
        }
            else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
            else if(cmd === 'clear') clear_song(message, server_queue);
            else if(cmd === 'volUp') volUp(message, server_queue);
            else if(cmd === 'volDown') volDown(message, server_queue);
        }
        
  }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    //If no song is left in the server queue. Leave the voice channel and delete the key and value pair from the global queue.
    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: volume })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(` Sto riproducendo "**${song.title}**"`)
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setAuthor('maiku', 'https://i.ibb.co/MCkG7wV/M-ROSSA-500.png', 'https://discord.gg/QNhpmbG3Sm')
        .setDescription(`[**Brano riprodotto correttamente**]`);
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(Embed);
    console.log(`[>] Sto riproducendo "${song.title}"`);
}

const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Devi essere in un canale vocale.');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`Non ci sono canzoni da skippare`);
    }
    message.react('');
    console.log(`[!] Brano skippato con successo`);
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

const clear_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Devi essere in un canale vocale.');
    message.react('');
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
    server_queue.songs = [];
    console.log(`[!] Coda azzerata`);
}

const volUp = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Devi essere in un canale vocale.');
    message.react('');
    volume = volume + 0.5;
    console.log(`[?] Volume aumentato di 0.5`);
}

const volDown = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Devi essere in un canale vocale.');
    message.react('');
    if (volume > 0.5) {
        volume = volume - 0.5;
        console.log(`[?] Volume diminuito di 0.5`);
    }
    console.log(`[?] Volume non diminuito [valore minimo raggiunto]`);
}
```

I tried looking at similar errors but on different codes but none of those fixes worked for me.
Can you help me fix this? Thanks

also take a look on the command handler

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return; 

  try {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args, client, Discord);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply(`Si è verificato un errore durante l'esecuzione del comando...`);
  }
})
```

Comment: The error is saying `message.member` is undefined in `message.member.voice.channel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Discord.js library actually do, but the error tells you that the param `member` in `message` it's `undefined`. Maybe it's because the first param that you send on the execute is not the `client`, it's `message`.

I think that it should be:

```
client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args, command, Discord);
```